# Exponential Growth and Decay : $y = a (1+r)^t$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

I know this is a really basic question for this website, but I can't find it anywhere else.

This is the question: "If you deposit $\$3,750$ in an account that pays $6\%$ annual interest compounded monthly, what is the balance of the account after $11$ years?"

The formula I'm using is $y = a (1+r)^t$, with a being the initial amount, $r$ being the rate in decimal form, and $t$ is time relative to the rate, which makes $y = 3,750(1+.06)^{132}$

How do I solve for the ending amount ($y$)?

Comment: It depends what the $6\%$ means. Probably it is the **nominal** annual rate. Then the monthly interest rate is $\frac{0.06}{12}$, which is $0.0025$. After $11$ years we have $(3750)(1.005)^{132}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better formula to use would be $$y=a\left(1+\frac{r}{k}\right)^{kt},$$ where $k$ is the number of times the interest is compounded per year. So, plugging in your information gives $$y=3750\left(1+\frac{.06}{12}\right)^{132}=\$7243.55$$

Comment: Thank you! Maybe you can help me with this? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1105557/exponential-growth-and-decay-compound-interest