# Exponential Growth and Decay / compound interest

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

This is the question: "If you want to have $\$75,000$ after $35$ years in your account that pays $12\%$ annual interest compounded quarterly, how much should you put in as your original investment?"

The formula I'm using is $y = a (1+r)^t$, with $a$ being the initial amount, $r$ being the rate in decimal form, and $t$ is time relative to the rate. Or $y = a (1+r/t)^t$

Although my biggest problem is that I'm not sure whether to have the $1+r$ or $1-r$.

So after plugging in what I have either:

$75000 = a (1-.12)^{35}$

$75000 = a (1+.12)^{35}$

or you can use this formula (preferably):

$75000 = a (1-.12/35)^{35}$

$75000 = a (1+.12/35)^{35}$

Comment: Do you want your investment to grow or shrink by 12% each year?  That's the difference between a positive and negative growth rate.

Comment: Although your biggest problem is important, you will also need to figure out how to handle the “compounded quarterly” part of the problem.

Comment: How much interest per quarter? How many quarters in the total time period?

Comment: Note that if interest is compounded $N$ times annually, then the principal at time $t$ is $$P(t) = P_0\left(1 + \frac{r}{N}\right)^{Nt}$$ where $P_0$ is the initial principal, $100r\%$ is the annual interest rate, and $t$ is the time in years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose I deposit $X$ dollars and leave it for say 25 interest-periods gaining 5% per interest period.

Then the amount in my account at the end of that process is $X (1.05)^{25} = 3.386X$

If I know the amount at the end of the period, $Y = 3.386X$ then obviously I can find out what X was also. Say the resulting amount is \$45000 - then the original deposit was $\frac{45000}{3.386} \to$ \$13288.63

Your problem is exactly like this - you just have extra steps to calculate what the interest rate is and how many interest periods you are talking about.